# Call finalize in shutdownHook could not work

Tags: java

In below code snippet, the `finalize()` method would never be called. But when I replace `finalize()` to `close()` in `addShutdownHook`. The `finalize()` method would be call. Is it a bug here?

```
public class Main {

    public Main() {
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(
            new Thread(
                new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                           finalize();
                        } catch (Throwable e) {
                            System.out.println(e);
                        }
                    }
            })
        );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Enter main");
        Main m = new Main();
        m = new Main();
        m = null;
        System.out.println("Before System.exit(0);");
        System.exit(0);
    }

    protected void finalize() {
        System.out.println("Call finalize()");
    }

    protected void close() {
        finalize();
    }
}
```

Comment: [Finalize is a method of the Object class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) which is the reason your `finalize` is not called. Does it really needs to be called finalize?

Comment: Don't call `finalize()` manually, let GC do its job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        try {
            finalize();
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}));
```

This calls the `finalize` method of the anonymous `Runnable` instance (which does nothing because it is the inherited `Object#finalize()`), not the one defined in your class. You can call the latter using:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        try {
            Main.this.finalize();
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}));
```

A much better way is to rename the method to avoid overriding `Object#finalize()` which is called when the garbage collector detects the object is no longer referenced.

Also note that in your code, you're registering *two* shutdown hooks (the constructor is called twice), so the method `finalize` will be called twice.

Comment: @haosdent this.finalize() will not work. As `this` would refer to the enclosing class i.e Runnable. You should read this for clarity https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html

Comment: Thank you very much! @AseemBansal and nikpon